# Echo a SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php

I've got an array that looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [version] => 2.0
        )

    [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => Active Fire Incident Page
            [link] => http://www.ci.austin.tx.us/fact/default.cfm
            [description] => This page provides information on active Austin/Travis County Fire incidents.  Data is updated every 3 minutes.

            [lastBuildDate] => Wed, 23 Nov 2016 10:59:38 PM GMT
            [copyright] => 2016 City of Austin. All rights reserved.
            [language] => en-us
            [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => E ST ELMO RD/SHERATON AVE
                    [link] => http://www.ci.austin.tx.us/fact/default.cfm
                    [description] => AFD - 4700 S Congress Ave - BOX -Structure Fire - Wed, 23 Nov 2016 10:51 PM 
                    [pubdate] => Wed, 23 Nov 2016 10:51 PM 
                )

        )

)
```

How would I go about echoing the last part of the array?  This section:

```
                    [title] => E ST ELMO RD/SHERATON AVE
                    [link] => http://www.ci.austin.tx.us/fact/default.cfm
                    [description] => AFD - 4700 S Congress Ave - BOX -Structure Fire - Wed, 23 Nov 2016 10:51 PM 
                    [pubdate] => Wed, 23 Nov 2016 10:51 PM
```

With this code:

```
echo $xml->channel->item->link;
```

I'm getting

```
Notice:Trying to get property of non-object
```

Comment: why do you need foreach? `echo $xml->channel->item->link;`

Comment: There will be more events that happen in the feed. I can do without it though. I feel like the [@attributes] is messing things up. is there a way to skip it?

Comment: $array['channel']->item->link works?

Comment: It seems as if $xml was not a SimpleXML Object. It looks a little bit strange that your dump says, it was an array. So, assuming you're dumping $xml in your question, it looks as if you need to access $xml['channel']->item->link

Comment: I'm getting a Notice:  Array to string conversion now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ($xml['channel'])->item->link;
```

Is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong code, try this

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $key => $product){
   echo $product->link;
```

OR directly

```
 echo $xml->channel->item->link;
```

Comment: i wonder who voted this up?! channel is not part of the simplexml object. Its an array that contains an object.